# Is this Depth First Search implementation tail recursive now?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tail-recursion, fold

I had this function for functionally traversing a graph:

```
private def dfs(current: RCell, rCellsMovedWithEdges: Vector[RCell], acc: Vector[RCell] = Vector()): Vector[RCell] = {
    current.edges.foldLeft(acc) {
      (results, next) =>
        if (results.contains(rCellsMovedWithEdges(next))) results
        else dfs(rCellsMovedWithEdges(next), rCellsMovedWithEdges, results :+ current)
    } :+ current
  }
```

Implementation taken from  [manuel kiessling here](https://manuel.kiessling.net/2016/02/15/scala-traversing-a-graph-in-a-functional-way/)

It's quite nice, but I'm worried the " :+ current" at the end is making it non-tail recursive.

I changed it to this:

```
private def dfs(current: RCell, rCellsMovedWithEdges: Vector[RCell]): Vector[RCell] = {

    @annotation.tailrec
    def go(current: RCell, rCellsMovedWithEdges: Vector[RCell], acc: Vector[RCell] = Vector()): Vector[RCell] = {
      current.edges.foldLeft(acc) {
        (results, next) =>
          if (results.contains(rCellsMovedWithEdges(next))) results
          else go(rCellsMovedWithEdges(next), rCellsMovedWithEdges, results :+ current)
      }
    }
    go(current, rCellsMovedWithEdges) :+ current
  }
```

but the compiler says the recursive call is not in tail position.

Is leftfold already tail recursive per chance?

If not, is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not tail recursive because the last call is not to `go`, but to `foldLeft`. There's no way it could be even mutually tail recursive, as `foldLeft` calls `go` multiple times. It's hard to make DFS tail recursive, as the recursive algorithm relies heavily on the call stack to keep track of your position in the tree. I would suggest not bothering if you can guarantee that your tree is shallow. Otherwise, you will need to pass around an explicit stack (`List` is a good choice here) and completely rewrite your code.

Answer (score 6):

You must essentially manually manage the stack if you want to implement DFS tail-recursively:

```
def dfs(start: RCell, rCellsMovedWithEdges: Vector[RCell]): Vector[RCell] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(stack: List[RCell], visited: Set[RCell], acc: Vector[RCell]): Vector[RCell] = stack match {
    case Nil => acc
    case head :: rest => {
      if (visited.contains(head)) {
        go(rest, visited, acc)
      } else {
        val expanded = head.edges.map(rCellsMovedWithEdges)
        val unvisited = expanded.filterNot(visited.contains)
        go(unvisited ++ rest, visited + head, acc :+ head)
      }
    }
  }
  go(List(start), Set.empty, Vector.empty)
}
```

Bonus: change `unvisited ++ rest` to `rest ++ unvisited` and you get BFS.